# Is it possible to save a folium object in Python?

Tags: python, folium

I am trying to write a script that uses folium to show two gpx traces. One is already computed (previsional trace) and another one that I update everyday (actual trace).

However, the script that generate the folium.PolyLine object Frome the GPX trace trace is quite long to run and therefore, I want to save the folium.PolyLine object that contains this trace. However, I don't find a way to save this object via folium' documentation.

How can I save this kind of Object ?

I have tried using the pickle package to save the folium.PolyLine object doing so :

```
#[...]

line = folium.PolyLine(points)

path = os.path(...)

with open(path, "w")as f:

    pickle.dump(line, path, -1)
```

But I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Pydroid3/script.py", line 372, in <module>

    pickle.dump(m, outp, -1)

_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function root at 0x75a65af0d0>: attribute lookup root on __main__ failed

/storage/emulated/0 $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can save a `folium` map image as an `html` file:

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[26, -80], height=500, width=750, zoom_start=8)
file_name = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DATA_FOLDERS/IMAGES/my_folium_map'
m.save(file_name + '.html')
```

then convert it to a `pdf` file, and then convert the `pdf` file to a `png` file:

```
!pip install pdfkit
!sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
import pdfkit
!pip install PyMuPDF
import fitz
options = {'javascript-delay': 500, 'page-size': 'Letter', 'margin-top': '0.0in', 'margin-right': '0.0in', 'margin-bottom': '0.0in', 'margin-left': '0.0in', 'encoding': "UTF-8", 'custom-header': [('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')]}
pdfkit.from_file(file_name + '.html',  (file_name + '.pdf'), options=options)
pdf_file = fitz.open(file_name + '.pdf')
page = pdf_file.load_page(0)
pixels = page.get_pixmap()
pixels.save(file_name + '.png')
pdf_file.close()
```

saved `png` file:

```
from PIL import Image
folium_png = Image.open(file_name + '.png')
display(folium_png)
```

[image]

**Note:** the `folium` `height` and `width` arguments determine the size of the image being saved:

```
folium.Map(..., height=500, width=750, ...)
```

Now if we want the *actual* `folium.Map` object we can save that as an `html` file:

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[26, -80])
m.save('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DATA_FOLDERS/IMAGES/some_folium_map.html')
```

then to retrieve that saved `folium.Map` object we `read` the `html` file:

```
file_name = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DATA_FOLDERS/IMAGES/some_folium_map.html'
a = open(file_name, 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
a = a.read()
```

parse the `str`ing to find the `attribution` `dict`ionary:

```
b = a[a.find('attribution') - 1:a.find('attribution') + (a[a.find('attribution') - 1:]).find('}') - 1]
```

then `pythonicize` the `str`ing and pass it as a `dict`ionary to the `folium.Map` function:

```
import ast
def pythonicize(some_string):
    some_new_string = some_string
    while some_string == some_new_string:
        if some_string.find('false') >= 0:
            some_new_string = some_string[:some_string.find('false')] + 'F' + some_string[some_string.find('false') + 1:]
        if some_new_string.find('true') >= 0:
            some_new_string = some_new_string[:some_new_string.find('true')] + 'T' + some_new_string[some_new_string.find('true') + 1:]
        if some_new_string.find('false') >= 0 or some_new_string.find('true') >= 0:
            some_string = some_new_string
    return ast.literal_eval('{' + some_new_string + '}')

m = folium.Map(**pythonicize(b))
m
```

where `m` is (again) the `folium.Map` object:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately that doesn't answer to my questions, maybe I was not clear enough. I want to save a folium object. With something like map.save(), as it is possible for example with numpy objects ( numpy.save(), bumpy load()). So I can re-edit the same folium object each time I run my script. Thank so much for your time.

Comment: With the html method, I have not seen a method to load as an folium object the html file. And, moreover, the file is quite hard to understand and parse with a classical html parser like xml.etree

Comment: @Lk Ncll gotcha. You want the actual folium Map object. I updated my answer to include that.

Comment: I have tried your solution. It allows to retrieve the folium Map object. however, the line of code where you get the dictionary does not work all the time. The dict of interest is the dict of the tileLayer section in the Html file. But sometimes there is also a attribution keyword in the Map object, but it is not a dict. To manage this issue I have added this line before the attribution find one : a = a[a.find('L.tileLayer'):]. Moreover I got the process to retrieve folium objects in the Html, thank you. It is quite fastidious however to get all the polylines and markers etc. But it works !