# How do I show a folium map in kivymd?

Tags: python, html, kivymd, folium

I have a list of hospital data,(including latitudes and longitudes). I am finding user's location and telling them which is the nearest hospital.  A folium map is created that shows mark on both, the nearest hospital location and the user's location. But that folium map is saved in a separete html file.

I wanted to convert the code to something executable. I did this to show the name of the hospital:

```
class Main_App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return MDLabel(text=f"Nearest hospital: {near_hosp}.", halign="center")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main_App().run()
```

But I don't know if it is possible to show the map's html file too? If so how?

Comment: Does this help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75928467/is-it-possible-to-save-a-folium-object-in-python/75931359#75931359)?