# Folium: How to show a map from a saved html file in ipynb

Tags: python, folium

I have a folium map saved locally as a html file, now I want to read that `map.html` file to show a map in another ipynb cell/notebook.

Minimum code to generate the local file:

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750]) 
m # to view the map if needed
m.save('map.html')
```

Esentially I'm trying to find any way to save a map locally (doesn't need to be html) and read it later in some other ipynb notebook.

I am able to find ways of sharing it on the [web](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389371/how-can-i-share-folium-map-on-the-web) but my use case is limited to ipynb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to save a folium object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75928467/is-it-possible-to-save-a-folium-object-in-python)

Comment: @ChristianKarcher Thanks for sharing that, it doesn't answer my question as saving the plot as a png/pdf will make it lose the interactiveness of the map. But looking at the comments on the answer you shared, there probably isn't a solution to what I'm looking for

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I cannot find any other way to save and reimport it into python. What about directly generating it in the jupyter notebook? You could save the args & kwargs used in folium.Map to generate the object again in the notebook?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't save the geo-dataframe to share it for another ipynb. I think I will look at how to share it on the web. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried loading it as an [`IFrame`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.IFrame) in the second `ipynb` ?

```
import folium

# op map
m = folium.Map([45.5236, -122.6750])

# adding a blue marker/icon
folium.Marker(location=[45.5236, -122.6750], icon=folium.Icon(color="blue")).add_to(m)

m.save("map.html") # saving it locally
```

---

```
from IPython.display import IFrame

IFrame(src="map.html", width=800, height=350)
```

Output (*in Jupyterlab*) :

[image]

Comment: This works! Interestingly it only worked on Jupyter notebook, but not on ipynb on VScode or PyCharm (maybe it is web-drive thing).